# Kendo Observable Change event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-observable

I have a kendo Obervable as follows:

```
var ViewModel = kendo.observable({
     ID: 1,
     TITLE: "SomeValue",
});
```

and then I have bound this as follows:

```
kendo.bind($(".bind-view"), ViewModel );
```

Now there is button on the page. When clicked I need to check if there are any changes to this `ViewModel`.

I have tried

```
    $(".ClearAnalysisInfo").on('click', function (event) { 
         ViewModel.bind("change", function (e) {
         //Some code
      });
  });
```

But I'm not able to get this ViewModel property whether it changed or not.

Comment: Can you show how does the html look like?

Comment: Isn't the purpose of an observable to use MVVM? Why use jquery to handle the click when you can bind a click function to the viewmodel?

Answer (score 2):

Binding the ObservableObject's [`change` event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject#events-change) of inside the button's `click` handler is too late. You need to do that immediately after the ObservableObject is created.

Inside the `change` handler, you will receive information about the changed **field**. Use this information to raise some JavaScript flag or save the details you need, so that you can use them later in the button's `click` handler.

```
var viewModelChanged = false;

var ViewModel = kendo.observable({
    ID: 1,
    TITLE: "SomeValue",
});

ViewModel.bind("change", function (e) {
    viewModelChanged = true;
});

$(".ClearAnalysisInfo").on('click', function (event) { 
    if (viewModelChanged) {
        // ...
    }
});
```